# how to represent number bigger than long in c

Tags: c

I want a variable to represent the number `600851475143` in C but this value is larger than the maximum value of long i.e `2147483647`.What data type should I use?

Comment: `unsigned long`? `long long`? `unsigned long long`? Use a bigint library?

Comment: ...strings? `double`? `long double`? Everything depends on your needs!

Comment: Search for C data types and its sizes. Some even compilers support a 128 bits integer.

Comment: You should tell us what are you going to do with that number if you want a better advice. You gave us too little info on the problem you are trrying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use integer type `long long`.
It is good for at least the range -9223372036854775807 <= x <= +9223372036854775807.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  long long big = 600851475143;
  printf("%lld\n", big);  // prints 600851475143
  return 0;
}
```

---

Alternatively, one could use `int64_t` or `uint64_t` - 64-bit types.

---

The range mentioned above is the *minimal* range specified in C11 5.2.4.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

Use an unsigned long. This will allow only numbers >= 0, but it will extend your range. I would make sure that your long type is 64-bit, as this will also extend your range of values.

You can also use gmplib, which is released under the LGPL: http://gmplib.org/

Comment: Probably a typo, but just to avoid leaving incorrect info in a post: "This will allow only numbers **>= 0**"

Comment: @SevenBits To insure the integer type is 64-bit, simple use `int64_t` or `uint64_t`.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Thanks, yes, it was a typo. I'll correct it now.

Answer (score 2):

Besides using an arbitrary precision integer math library, as suggested by @H2CO3, which is probably you best bet if you plan to work with such big numbers without worrying for overflows, you should check your compiler/platform documentation for the maximum representable number.

If you don't need signed arithmetic you could use `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`, otherwise `signed long long`. Keep in mind that the standard doesn't mandate their size exactly, only a minimum is specified (from C99 draft standard - Annex E):

```
#define LONG_MAX +2147483647
#define LONG_MIN -2147483647
#define LLONG_MAX +9223372036854775807
#define LLONG_MIN -9223372036854775807
// [...]
#define ULONG_MAX 4294967295
#define ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: but the size of thoose types it self is implementation defined again, isn't it? Or why on all plattforms i know long's size differs in 32 and 64 bit arch's?

Comment: @Zaibis  Lorenzo Donati posted the _minimum_.  The values are implementation defined, but will _at least_ cover the above range, thus a `long` could be 4 or more 8-bit bytes.