# C code for multiplication of even numbers returns 0

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
int i;
int mul = 1;
for(i = 50; i > 1; i--){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        mul = mul * i;
    }
}
printf("\n Multiplication is %d",mul);
}
```

The answer comes zero. Tried it many times but always shows zero.

Comment: what number do you expect? does it fit into 32-bit signed integer?

Comment: Try to put intermediate `printf()` inside the loop and the if-condition and analyze the results. It's always a good practice in order to create a sort of debug.

Comment: `mul` is much bigger than int

Comment: Using python to calculate, product from 2 to 50 is 520469842636666622693081088000000. And signed int overflow is undefined behaviour in C and C++. Can your please tell us what compiler you use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect unsigned integer multiply overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-multiply-overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said before `mul` is much bigger than `int` and even `long`.

You should use some else struct, you can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675101/how-to-represent-number-bigger-than-long-in) and learn how to implement. number that bigger than long.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

What you should do to debug:

```
for(i = 50; i > 1; i--){

    printf("i: %d i%2: %d mul: %d\n", i, i%2, mul);

    if(i % 2 == 0){
        mul = mul * i;
    }

    printf("i: %d i%2: %d mul: %d\n", i, i%2, mul);
}
```

But as other have pointed out, the answer is too big to fit in `int`. And when you overflow an `int` the behavior is undefined, so it's not guaranteed that this code prints zero.